# Python typehint every type except one

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

If I for example want to let the user to input any type to the function except `list` is there a way I can do that?

in pseudocode:

```py
def some_func(arg: AllTypesExceptOne(list)) -> None:
    print(arg)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?  Seems smelly to me.  What if I have a custom type that looks exactly like a `list`?

Comment: @0x5453 i need to append any other data than list to a list, but all good now